# Android include parameterizable layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I hate repeating same code. I have one activity with:

```
<include layout="@layout/tmpl_stars22" />
```

And the second with:

```
<include layout="@layout/tmpl_stars36" />
```

Included layout contains:

```
....
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/star1"
    android:layout_width="22dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_star_off"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
....
```

The second layout uses 36dp picture. Can I somehow avoid having two files? I have not found how to pass some parameters inside included layout. https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

**Conclusion** - not possible

Comment: I think you should convert this layout to a custom view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom view and use it in your layouts.

exmaple:

custom_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgview" />
</LinearLayout>
```

CustomView.java

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {

    int width = -1;
    int height = -1;
    ImageView imageview;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        inflate(context, R.layout.custom_layout, this)
        initViews();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        inflate(context, R.layout.custom_layout, this);
        int[] attributes = {
                android.R.attr.width,     //=====> 0
                android.R.attr.height     //=====> 1
        };
        TypedArray attrSet = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attributes);
        width = attrSet.getDimension(0, -1);  //android.R.attr.width,
        height = attrSet.getDimension(1, -1); //android.R.attr.height
        attrSet.recycle();
        initViews();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        inflate(context, R.layout.custom_layout, this);
        initViews();
    }

    public void initViews(){
        imageview = findViewById(R.id.imgview);
        if(width > -1){
            imageview.setWidth(width);
        }
        if(height > -1){
            imageview.setHeight(height);
        }
    }
}
```

and when you want use it:

activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CustomView
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I just tried to show you the base structure and you should customize this codes for your case.

Comment: Thanks but custom view is a overkill in this case.

Comment: @LeosLiterak So in that case, your question's answer is a straight "No"... There is no way to set a dynamic data to xml file, without coding...

Comment: Ok, I understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can add size on include tag :

```
<include layout="@layout/tmpl_stars"
    android:layout_width="22dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/star1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_star_off"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

> You can also override all the layout parameters (any android:layout_* attributes) of the included layout's root view by specifying them in the  tag. For example:

Comment: Nice hack, but the picture is just one part of the included layout. upvoted anyway for passing layout information.

Comment: So I haven't any solutions, sorry

Comment: Or you can create a custom view with some parameters from parents that you apply on child